# How to write excluding sum query?

Tags: sql

I have a `values` table:

```
+------------+---------+
| name       | value   |
+------------+---------+
| parameter1 | 53.8462 |
| parameter2 | 7.6923  |
| parameter3 | 23.0769 |
| parameter4 | 15.3846 |
+------------+---------+
```

What is the query for sum values of the three last parameters (`parameter 2`, `parameter 3`, `parameter 4`) without the first parameter (`parameter1`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bit simplistic, but can't you do this:

`select sum(value) from table where name != 'parameter2'`

If what you are really after is the sum past n-th value, you could do this (in SQL Server):

```
WITH OrderedRows AS
(
    SELECT name, value,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM table 
) 
SELECT sum(value) 
FROM OrderedRows 
WHERE RowNumber > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(value) tot
FROM table
WHERE name='parameter2' OR name='parameter3' OR name='parameter4'
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(value) tot
FROM table
WHERE name<>'parameter1'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are specif to this only

```
SELECT SUM(value) tot
FROM table
WHERE name<>'parameter1'
```

but if you need some generic solution than do not use this

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(value) from values where name!='parameter1';
```

In place of ! you could also use <>.

Comment: There is no row in the table with value 'parameter' in the `name` column. Did you mean 'parameter1' ?

Answer (score 1):

with some null-checking, so the `sum` can still work:

```
SELECT SUM(coalesce(value, 0)) your_total
FROM table
WHERE coalesce(name, '') <> 'parameter1'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to sum the last three columns, even on bigger tables than your example, you are looking for **moving window functions**.

In **Oracle** you can write

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT 'parameter1' PAR, 2 VAL FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'parameter2' PAR, 3 VAL FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'parameter3' PAR, 5 VAL FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'parameter4' PAR, 7 VAL FROM DUAL
)
SELECT PAR, SUM(VAL) OVER (ORDER BY PAR ROWS 2 PRECEDING) LAST3SUM FROM T;
```

This would yield to

```
PAR      LAST3SUM
---------- ----------
parameter1      2
parameter2      5
parameter3     10
parameter4     15
```

You shoudl look at the [Oracle Documentation about Analytic Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) and keep the following in mind:

- Note that the query uses `SUM`, but no `GROUP BY`. This is because we are not *aggregating* data, but calculating the `SUM` *for each row* we select.
- Note that *order* is important, in my example I `ORDER BY PAR`, but you can as well order by any other column available in your query.

[Oracle Data Warehousing Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/analysis.htm#DWHSG021) also discusses windowing functions, giving a lot of useful examples.